# creating a switch and case in a cursorloader

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-contacts

I'm not even sure this will work, but this is how we learn so don't tell me this is broken yet :)

I'm trying my first cursorloader.  I THINK I setup my onCreateLoader method correctly, but I'm not sure how to setup my onLoadFinished and onLoadReset methods.  This is my first time working with switch and cases.  Any help filling in those 2 methods would be greatly appreciated.

This class retrieves contact phone and contact email for the selected contact ID. What's interesting is that as-is, the code take's the contact email address and sets it as the text for the phone number.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.content.CursorLoader;
import android.content.Loader;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Pete on 6/19/13.
 */
public class ContactDetails extends Activity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    TextView tvContactName, tvPhoneNum, tvPhoneType, tvPhoneFull,
            tvEmailAdd, tvEmailType, tvEmailFull,
            tvAddress, tvAddType, tvAddFull;

    String contactId, contactName, phoneType, phoneFull, phoneNum1,
            emailAdd, emailType, emailFull,
            address, addType, addFull;

    private static final int LOADER_PHONE = 2;
    private static final int LOADER_EMAIL = 3;

    //Contact List query arguments
    Uri uri;
    String[] projection, selectionArgs;
    String selection, sortOrder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contactinfo);

        initialize();

        contactId = getIntent().getStringExtra("contactId");
        contactName = getIntent().getStringExtra("contactName");
        tvContactName.setText(contactName);

        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_PHONE, null, this);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_EMAIL, null, this);
    }

    public void initialize() {
        tvContactName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvContactName);
        tvPhoneNum = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneNum);
        tvPhoneType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneType);
        tvPhoneFull = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneFull);
        tvEmailAdd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEmailAdd);
        tvEmailType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEmailType);
        tvEmailFull = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEmailFull);
        tvAddress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
        tvAddType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAddType);
        tvAddFull = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvAddFull);
    }
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        switch (id) {
        case LOADER_PHONE:
            uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
            projection = new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
            };
            selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +
                    " = " + contactId;
            selectionArgs = null;
            sortOrder = null;
            break;

        case LOADER_EMAIL:
            uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
            projection = new String[] {
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS
            };
            selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + 
                    " = " + contactId;
            selectionArgs = null;
            sortOrder = null;
            break;
        }
        return new CursorLoader(this, uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                // Extract the phone number
                phoneFull = cursor.getString(
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                tvPhoneFull.setText(phoneFull);
            }
        }       
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

here's the currently commented out while loop for setting the email info:

```
uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
projection = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS
};
selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + 
        " = " + contactId;
selectionArgs = null;
sortOrder = null;
Cursor emailCursor = getContentResolver().query(
        uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
    // Extract email address
    emailFull = emailCursor.getString(
            emailCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));
    tvEmailFull.setText(emailFull);
}
emailCursor.close();
```